# Navbar and sidebar css hover after problem

Tags: html, css

Some problems with my CSS..

1. Navigation bar animation does not work how it should work on nav a:hover as well as a::after is absolute leftside somewhere hidden and I need to use like more like over 100% width to use it work somehow "good".
2. Can someone explain me how to make grid responsive where is sidebar and main grid on this code? If one of the sidebars will be bigger(more data), I want to make main bar same height as sidebar and let footer grid still visible?
3. Can someone show me how to make same navigation bar animation on sidebar just vertically line? Thank you very much.

Is there any way to set in third sidebar box another a class conditions? like for example let the text be black no decorations without any a css styles which are already setted for a class?

Thank you very much for your help.. If you see anything bad pls tell me :D

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    background-color: #c9c9c9;
}


/* Layout CSS Title, Menu, Main, Sidebar, Footer */
.layout {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 5fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.1fr 0.1fr 1.2fr 0.3fr;
    grid-template-areas:
    "title title title title"
    "nav nav nav sidebar"
    "main main main sidebar"
    "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.title{
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    grid-area: title;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

nav {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    grid-area: nav;

    margin: 0;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

nav a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 3em;
    position: relative;

}

nav a::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 0.4em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 160, 0);
    bottom: -1em;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;

}

nav a:hover::after {
    width: 60%;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 160, 0);
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:first-child {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 3em;
}

main {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    grid-area: main;
}
.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
}

footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:550px) {
    .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 0.2fr 1fr 0.5fr 0.2fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "title"
    "nav"
    "main"
    "sidebar"
    "footer";
    }
}

/* Sidebar CSS */

.box_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    float: right;
    display: grid;
}
  
.box {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float: right;
}
  
.box_title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom:  1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
}

.box_title i {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
  
.box_content {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.box_content a{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box_content ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.box_content li {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box_content a:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 160, 0);
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.box_online {
    font-size: 10px; 
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: rgb(5, 148, 0);
}

.box_offline {
    font-size: 10px; 
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: rgb(148, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="cz">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/style.css">-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Krušnohorský svět</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <a href="index.php">Domů</a>
            <a href="switcher.php">Menu 1</a>
            <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
        </nav>

        <main>

        </main>

        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="box_container">    
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box_title"><i class='material-icons'>menu</i>Uživatelský panel</div>
                        <div class="box_content">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Můj profil</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Uživatelé</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Nastavení</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Odhlásit se</a></li>   
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box_title"><i class='material-icons'>menu</i>Admin panel</div>
                        <div class="box_content">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Správa uživatelů</a></li>
                                <li><a href="phpmyadmin">PhpMyAdmin</a></li>  
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box_title"><i class='material-icons'>people</i>Online uživatelé</div>
                        <div class="box_content">
                            <ul>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_online'>circle</i>Admin</a>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i>User_+</a>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_online'>circle</i>sdfsdfdfds</a>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_online'>circle</i>Admin</a>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_online'>circle</i>Admin</a>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_online'>circle</i>Admin</a>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_online'>circle</i>Admin</a>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_online'>circle</i>Admin</a>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_online'>circle</i>Admin</a>
                                <a href=""><i class='material-icons box_online'>circle</i>Admin</a>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            
        </footer>

    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!